# Accessing variables when scraping website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm currently trying to scrape a website (url in code below), however when I pull out the section of html I'm looking to work with, all I get is the variable names of the information I'm looking for. The actual values for the variables are present when I manually inspect the page's html but I assume when I scrape the page that all I see is the website referencing variables from elsewhere.

I'm hoping someone can help me try to access this information. I have tried just scraping the website's html using selenium, however I seem just get back the same html that I scrape when using requests (maybe I'm doing it incorrectly).

This is a refined version of my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/drinks/Beer-Ciders?sortDirection=asc&page=1'
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
sel = Selector(text=html)

html_info = (sel.xpath('//*[@id="vueSearchResults"]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/a').extract())

print(html_info)
```

This then returns the following:

```
['<a data-qa="search-product-title" v-bind:href="Product.Url" v-bind:title="Product.FullDisplayName" v-bind:data-productid="Product.ProductId" data-oc-click="searchProductClick" class="p text-default-font"> {{Product.DisplayName}} </a>']
```

From which I want to get the actual value of 'Product.FullDisplayName'. I'd appreciate it if some can point me in the right direction as to accessing this variable's information, or a way to scrape the website's html - as seen by a user traversing the webpage. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to scrape in that webpage ?

Comment: Look at `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: vue is virtual dom library, you need to run javascript to get rendered page, that means you need selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can either use [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) or [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library as they both serves the same purpose when it comes to downloading the page.

This website does not serve the complete data through single API. You can get most of the data like product name, url, image & size by utilising this url `https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/drinks/Beer-Ciders?sortDirection=asc&page=1`.  But, for price & unit price you have to send the POST request through this API  `https://groceries.aldi.ie/api/product/calculatePrices` along with passing request headers & payload.

Just for the demonstration the below code will give you products name. Similarly, you can loop through other fields to grab the data.

**Code**

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}


url = 'https://groceries.aldi.ie/en-GB/drinks/Beer-Ciders?sortDirection=asc&page=1'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
data = tree.xpath('//div[@class="products-search-results"]/@data-context')
product_name = json.loads(data[0])

for each_product in product_name['SearchResults']:
    print(each_product['FullDisplayName'])
```

**Output(Truncated)**

```
American Style Premium Lager 4 X 500ml Brookston
Traditional Irish Cider Apple Cider 8 X 500ml Cullen's
Premium Lager 500ml San Marcos
Cider Apple 8 X 500ml Orchard Thieves
Hop House500ml Can 8 X 500ml Guinness
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam, that's super helpful! By any chance could you give me a small example as to how to send POST requests through an API for price & unit price? I'm quite new to non-straightforward scraping.